# Rails HTTP Ping to unreliable Target

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, heroku, client

I would like to send an HTTP GET request to an ip address and port to determine if there is a device online that can respond at that address.

I want to have a relatively reasonable timeout so that my application does not hang while connecting, if there's no. I have been using `Net::HTTP`, but there does not seem to be a way to set a timeout when using an ip address.

```
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(ip_address, '/index.html', port)
```

Is there a best practice or better method to perform this request or a way to set a timeout in `Net::HTTP` when using an ip address rather than domain name?

I'm using Ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 4.1.0 with hosting on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no major difference between requesting via an ip address or by dns name, in the latter case DNS query is made and usually a `Host`-header is set, after that request is done via the ip.

In `Net::HTTP` there's `open_timeout` setting that raises `Net::OpenTimeout` when set if connection cannot be established during that period. By default it's `nil` which means 'forever'

Comment: Thanks. I was using class methods which didn't expose this option, but I see now that there are instance methods which do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can see about HTTParty [gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). This gem provide many options and easy to use.

You set timeout for the request to return the response

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://www.google.co.in/', timeout: 60)
```

timeout is in seconds.

or in Net http you can set as,

```
uri = URI.parse(ip_address + '/index.html')
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
begin
  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http|
    http.read_timeout = 100 #Default is 60 seconds
    http.request(request)
  }
rescue Net::ReadTimeout => e  
   puts e.message
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for. In the `Net::HTTP`-class there is `read_timeout`-setter. See here: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-read_timeout-3D